# Actualizar datos automáticamente asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

estoy planificando un sistema web en asp.net con c# y mientras hacia el análisis note que es posible que necesitara que se me actualicen los datos automáticamente. Aquí les dejo la cuestión:

Ejemplo: tengo un formulario que es para un mesero, en el cual este elige el pedido de cierta mesa u este se guardara en la base de datos, pues también tengo un formulario que seria como para la cocina donde se deben mostrar los pedidos para que se preparen.

La duda es que quiero hacer que se muestren inmediatamente o casi, lo único que me llega a la mente es programar una consulta que se ejecute cada ciertos segundos pero como me refiero a un sistema que contendrá múltiples formularios y tablas y muchos datos tengo la duda si es la mejor forma efectuarlo. He estado investigando pero no encuentro algo que me ayude, existe alguna tecnología o método   que pueda utilizar para resolver ese problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has tomando en cuenta las notificaciones PUSH (estilo facebook), solo que en vez de colocar el icono de notificaciones realices una acción, en tu caso sería agregar la orden.
Hay varias opciones, la más usada (o una de las más usadas) en .net es [SignalR](https://www.codemag.com/article/1210071/The-Simplest-Thing-Possible-Creating-Push-Notifications-with-SignalR).
y acá un [ejemplo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t90kJr03og).

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia leeré sobre signal r

Answer (score 1):

No puedo comentar, así que dejaré la respuesta:

Puedes emplear PushContentStream en un método de una aplicación WebApi, mandando notificaciones a todo cliente que se suscriba a dichas notificaciones. La implementación es rápida y sencilla, yo la tengo implementada en varios proyectos comerciales. Te dejo un ejemplo en el que hacen la llamada con AJAX, pero la lógica es la misma dependiendo de la tecnología que desees emplear...  [www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/push-notification-in-web-application-using-web-api-and-pushcontentstream/](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/push-notification-in-web-application-using-web-api-and-pushcontentstream/)

En el ejemplo se muestra un cliente de mensajería, pero puedes devolver objetos y emplearlos dependiendo de tus necesidades.